# I have an issue regarding Android Auto media duration feature

Tags: android, android-auto, mediabrowserservice, android-automotive

I just developed media application with android automotive support everything is working fine but i have an issue with new design of automotive OS like in previous design there is no duration for media streams but now they added duration of a media i don't want it like i want to hide it because i am playing live streams. If it can't be hide then i want to to do count up timer but i do not know how to do it using media session.

here is my code for setting media session.

```
mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder()
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "title")
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "genre")
                .putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, 0)
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI, "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/peppers.png")
                .build());
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Set a negative duration on [`MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadata.html#METADATA_KEY_DURATION)

> A negative duration indicates that the duration is unknown (or
>   infinite).

```
mediaSession.setMetadata(new MediaMetadata.Builder()
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST, "title")
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, "genre")
                .putLong(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, -1L) //Negative duration means the duration is unknown
                .putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART_URI, "https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/peppers.png")
                .build());
```

Comment: i did this but it shows 00:00 as a duration.... how can i start count up timer or hide this textview any idea?

Comment: i am using exoplayer to play media live streams

Comment: here is my question on Android Auto community https://support.google.com/androidauto/thread/12400850?hl=en&pli=1#